How to convert beta coefficient to actual change?
I found an interpretation in an academic article. It mentioned:

Firms that experienced EOD manipulation have 3.31% fewer citations in general, and the number jumps to 7.49% if it is a subsequent manipulation. Thus, 3.31% and 7.49% equate to decreases in citations for an innovating firm of 6 and 14, subsequently.

I understand how to convert the beta coefficient to percentage change, but I'm not sure how to interpret that as the actual change in the dependent variable.

Take the starting value of the variable and multiply that by the percentage change.
